# I am trying to write stored procedure to insets values and if record exist then select that row but it is giving me invalid use of group statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write stored procedure to insets values and if record exist then select that row but it is giving me invalid use of group statement

I have written below: -

TRY 1:- error :- invalid use of group statement

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insusers`(IN enterprise_id varchar(40),IN enterprise_name varchar(40),IN email_id varchar(40))
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE email_id = email_id;
    IF COUNT(*) < 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO user(enterprise_id,user_name,email_id) 
    VALUES (enterprise_id,enterprise_name,email_id);
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = last_insert_id();
    ELSE
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_id = email_id;
    END IF;
END
```

TRY 2 :- error :- Not able to insert new values

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insusers`(IN enterprise_id varchar(40),IN enterprise_name varchar(40),IN email_id varchar(40))
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count FROM user WHERE email_id = email_id;
    IF count < 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO user(enterprise_id,user_name,email_id) 
    VALUES (enterprise_id,enterprise_name,email_id);
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = last_insert_id();
    ELSE
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_id = email_id;
    END IF;
END
```

Please help me with solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. I have this suggestions: 1) You van improve code formatting so it is easier to help, 2) try using count (*) or count (column) instead of count(), 3) you can declare a variable for the count, or a better way is to use an 'exists' clause

Comment: Sorry I'll do that.

Comment: @LMigMa49 code format done

Comment: `IF COUNT(*) < 1 THEN` From what table the server should to calculate the count?

Comment: `WHERE email_id = email_id` Both `email_id` are procedure parameter values.

Comment: How is the engine supposed to figure out which email_id is the field and which is the variable ?  You can use backticks to distinguish.  I am voting to close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use `BEGIN` and `END` to separate `IF` clauses, also use `@` to distinguish between variables and columns. Hope this helps:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insusers`(IN @enterprise_id varchar(40),IN @enterprise_name varchar(40),IN @email_id varchar(40))
    BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE email_id = @email_id)<1) BEGIN
      INSERT INTO user(enterprise_id,user_name,email_id) 
      VALUES (@enterprise_id,@enterprise_name,@email_id);
      SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = last_insert_id();
    END ELSE BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_id = @email_id;
    END
END
```